# Does full backup or simple backup also take snapshot of db schema as well as data

Tags: sql

Does full or simple backup back up the database schema?
that is in following scenario:
1. do full backup
2. add some tables and columns in some table; drop some tables and some columns in some table
3. do restore with the full backup file
4. does that schema get back to the state it backup?

Comment: what db-engine are you talking about?

Comment: Generally the answer is "Yes, the schema gets backed up and restored". But your question was too vague to be certain about this. What database server are you using? What method are you using for backup and restore?

Answer (score 1):

In general the answer is yes. But you'd have to clarify on what db server you're talking about and how the backups are being done.

**EDIT :** A full backup will back everything up.

Comment: I am using ms sql server 2k 2k5 and 2k8